# A newly added Go lang file is not recognized by VSCode or go build

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I use Visual Studio code to modify go lang code.

When I create a new file in the explorer of VSCode by the right-click menu, write some code, and execute `go build`, the new file is ignored.
The `go build` results say the strucs in the new file are undefined, because the file is ignored.

When I copy an existing file in the explorer by dragging the existing file, the new file is not ignored and redeclaration errors occur, correctly.

How to make VScode or go lang recognize newly added files to build?

Comment: Any chance you don't save the file with changes?

Comment: @zerkms Thank you. I tried it again. A newly added file is not ignored. It was ignored because probably the package was wrong. And I found that the package name of a newly created file and its parent directory name must be the same for VSCode to autocomplete import path. Otherwise, the newly added file is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

It was ignored because probably the package was wrong.

I found that the package name of a newly created file and its parent directory name must be the same for VSCode to autocomplete import path.

Otherwise, the newly added file is ignored.